# DS18B20 stopped recently

Tags: pi-3b+, pi-zero, sensor, ds18b20, 1-wire

I have read a few posts here on my issue, notably [DS18B20 not detected by Raspberry Pi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/38554/ds18b20-not-detected-by-raspberry-pi?rq=1), but unfortunately none of the suggestions worked for my issue. I am seeking advice on additional troubleshooting measures that I can undertake.

I have used **DS18B20** sensors for several years with Arduino & RPi boards. In one particular arrangement, I didn't pay attention to the data since I had a DHT11 and a BME680 to corroborate the readings. Unfortunately, I have a monthly SQL TRUNCATE table operation and I cannot provide a specific date when the DS18B20 (or RPi OS) stopped creating the corresponding folder in /sys/bus/w1/devices owing regularly scheduled unattended update/upgrade operations in my farm. These sensors (I have a dozen+ of these) work presently in Arduino boards without issues. The failures occur with **RPi0W** and **RPi3B** boards.

The corresponding /boot/config.txt file has the following entry:

```
dtoverlay=w1-gpio-pullup,gpiopin=4
```

I've used modprobe as follows:

```
$ sudo modprobe w1_gpio
$ sudo modprobe w1_therm
```

I've confirmed that the corresponding processes are active by using the following command:

```
$ lsmod | grep w1
w1_therm               24576  0
w1_gpio                16384  0
wire                   40960  2 w1_gpio,w1_therm
$
```

When I explore /sys/bus/w1/devices, I do not find the folders with the *28-* prefix for each DS18B20 sensor in the setup. I sometimes use multiple DS18B20 sensors in parallel and naturally when the solution was working each sensor had its unique *28-* folder. The sensors are not in parasitic operation and there is a 4.7K resistor between data and 3.3VDC pins for the sensors. (Just to reiterate *with due apologies for restating*, the sensors were working previously on the same boards and are currently working with several different Arduino boards).

The RPi3 board is as follows:

```
$ uname -a
Linux raspbari9 5.4.70-v7+ #1348 SMP Wed Oct 7 16:14:38 BST 2020 armv7l GNU/Linux
$
```

I noticed that others had provided some boot messages. Here is one sample from my RPi3 board:

```
$ sudo vcdbg log msg
001530.977: brfs: File read: /mfs/sd/config.txt
001532.132: brfs: File read: 1823 bytes
001581.356: HDMI:EDID error reading EDID block 0 attempt 0
001582.618: HDMI:EDID error reading EDID block 0 attempt 1
001583.878: HDMI:EDID error reading EDID block 0 attempt 2
001585.139: HDMI:EDID error reading EDID block 0 attempt 3
001586.399: HDMI:EDID error reading EDID block 0 attempt 4
001587.660: HDMI:EDID error reading EDID block 0 attempt 5
001588.919: HDMI:EDID error reading EDID block 0 attempt 6
001590.180: HDMI:EDID error reading EDID block 0 attempt 7
001591.440: HDMI:EDID error reading EDID block 0 attempt 8
001592.700: HDMI:EDID error reading EDID block 0 attempt 9
001593.718: HDMI:EDID giving up on reading EDID block 0
001596.151: brfs: File read: /mfs/sd/config.txt
001597.199: gpioman: gpioman_get_pin_num: pin LEDS_PWR_OK not defined
001615.644: brfs: File read: 1823 bytes
001620.795: gpioman: gpioman_get_pin_num: pin WL_LPO_CLK not defined
001620.819: gpioman: gpioman_get_pin_num: pin BT_ON not defined
001620.838: gpioman: gpioman_get_pin_num: pin WL_ON not defined
001795.608: gpioman: gpioman_get_pin_num: pin DISPLAY_DSI_PORT not defined
001796.854: gpioman: gpioman_get_pin_num: pin LEDS_PWR_OK not defined
001796.918: *** Restart logging
... <N.B. removed several lines related to HDMI messages; I used headless mode of operation>
001833.789: dtb_file 'bcm2709-rpi-2-b.dtb'
001838.362: brfs: File read: /mfs/sd/bcm2709-rpi-2-b.dtb
001838.386: Loading 'bcm2709-rpi-2-b.dtb' to 0x100 size 0x66dd
001851.027: brfs: File read: 26333 bytes
001869.401: brfs: File read: /mfs/sd/overlays/overlay_map.dtb
001938.351: brfs: File read: 1463 bytes
001942.056: brfs: File read: /mfs/sd/config.txt
001942.603: dtparam: i2c_arm=on
001950.328: dtparam: spi=on
001957.160: dtparam: audio=on
001967.404: brfs: File read: 1823 bytes
001990.603: brfs: File read: /mfs/sd/overlays/w1-gpio-pullup.dtbo
001996.328: Loaded overlay 'w1-gpio-pullup'
001996.345: dtparam: gpiopin=4
001997.649: dtparam: pullup=1
002024.368: brfs: File read: 1171 bytes
002027.223: brfs: File read: /mfs/sd/cmdline.txt
002027.283: Read command line from file 'cmdline.txt':
002027.307: 'console=serial0,115200 console=tty1 root=PARTUUID=5e3da3da-02 rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline fsck.repair=yes rootwait quiet splash plymouth.ignore-serial-consoles'
003961.076: gpioman: gpioman_get_pin_num: pin EMMC_ENABLE not defined
004007.597: gpioman: gpioman_get_pin_num: pin WL_ON not defined
004011.483: brfs: File read: 166 bytes
004414.835: brfs: File read: /mfs/sd/kernel7.img
004414.859: Loading 'kernel7.img' to 0x8000 size 0x581110
004414.891: Device tree loaded to 0x2eff9400 (size 0x6be9)
004420.495: gpioman: gpioman_get_pin_num: pin SDCARD_CONTROL_POWER not defined
007492.364: vchiq_core: vchiq_init_state: slot_zero = 0xf7580000, is_master = 1
007496.776: hdmi: HDMI:hdmi_get_state is deprecated, use hdmi_get_display_state instead
007502.305: TV service:host side not connected, dropping notification 0x00000002, 0x00000002, 0x00000023
$
```

Obviously, this is some self-inflicted operator/user error. All suggestions are welcome since I would like to get more usage out of the many DS18B20 sensors that I have. Many thanks.

Kind regards.

Comment: (1) I once found that 1-wire has conflict with I2C. So one troubleshooting trick is to disable I2C. (2) And if you have recently updated buster, w1_therm driver might no longer work. (3) if you have a spare micoSD card, you might like to start with a fresh buster with clean config files, try my little python code, which is copy & run, auto detect and print results. This is to verify that clean config files can still run your 1-Wire hard ware: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/100203/ds18b20-temperature-sensor-rpi-3-4-driver-wiring-detection-and-python-progr/100244#100244. Cheers.

Comment: Thx @tlfong01! (1) Understand your suggestion rather well owing to the challenges in reading DHTxx with I2C. :) Disabling I2C on the RPi3 didn't resolve the issue (2) Is there another driver that I could use instead of w1_therm? (3) For the RPi3, started with the March Buster image (owing to personal OCD challenges, installed all other supporting pacakges too) but still no 28- folder under /.../devices. Will retry will new August Buster image and nothing except support for DS18B20 and report back here. Code is not an issue since I have boatloads of variations in Python & C/C++. Kind regards.

Comment: Thx again @tlfong01! Your suggestion (3) worked!! I used Aug Buster image & enabled only 1-wire & SSH (for my headless work). Voila, w/o touching any of the existing DS18B20 sensors, I found the three 28- folders under /.../devices. Guess all the updates/upgrades & my other code messed up the 1-wire access to the DS18B20 sensors. Appreciate your nudge & advice. Kind regards.

Comment: How nice to hear the good news! Cheers.